# Angular js ng-repeat work based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have requirement where i have two table ,i want logic like if id==1 then only ng-repeat works

$(#1).(ng-repeat work) something like this

```
eg: <table id="1">
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
<td></td> 
</table>

<table id="2">
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
<td></td> 
</table>
```

I want control something like where id is 1 or 2 there only ng-repeat work.i dont want to change model.

Fiddle Link:-http://jsfiddle.net/alokranjan39/7MhLd/575/

Thanks

Comment: do you means ng-repeat will take effect where row with id is 1 or 2?

Comment: To be honest question is not clear to me.

Comment: @edisonthk yes i want ng-repeat work where id is 1

Comment: @AniketKulkarni  in above case ng-repeat will work for both table,I want it should work only for one where id is 1

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly. What you have to use is $index in ng-repeat. It helps to track index nos for traversal. $index will give you that "Id". Check if this helps.

```
<li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:q as results">
      [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
    </li>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat